# How can I include custom modules in a Django app

Tags: python, django, module

I'm really new to Python and Django. I created a class in Python that I would like to use in a Django application. It doesn't seem like it belongs in it's own application, how can I include it in my django app?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put it [in a module somewhere](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) and import it.