# Including repeated view function into multiple views?

Tags: python, django

I have the following function in many views of many of my apps. Like the following:

```
def json_response(data):
    return HttpResponse(
        simplejson.dumps(data),
        content_type = 'application/json; charset=utf8'
    )
```

How would I include this on all of my apps' views.py? Define it in a single app and just import from it?

```
from main.global import simplejson
```

Also, is there a github page of a well organized django project that I can look at?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I include custom modules in a Django app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576060/how-can-i-include-custom-modules-in-a-django-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can just define it in a single view, or a utils file, or whatever you want, and just import it in all of your views. I frequently do this with ubiquitous functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using django 1.3, a class based view can be used to abstract this function. You would simply extend your view from a base view that would return json of whatever is passed in. You would save a file with this class at some common location (as described in the answer linked in the comment by Ignacio).

In fact, this is one of the example types in the [documentation for class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/#more-than-just-html):

```
from django import http
from django.utils import simplejson as json

class JSONResponseMixin(object):
    def render_to_response(self, context):
        "Returns a JSON response containing 'context' as payload"
        return self.get_json_response(self.convert_context_to_json(context))

    def get_json_response(self, content, **httpresponse_kwargs):
        "Construct an `HttpResponse` object."
        return http.HttpResponse(content,
                                 content_type='application/json',
                                 **httpresponse_kwargs)

    def convert_context_to_json(self, context):
        "Convert the context dictionary into a JSON object"
        # Note: This is *EXTREMELY* naive; in reality, you'll need
        # to do much more complex handling to ensure that arbitrary
        # objects -- such as Django model instances or querysets
        # -- can be serialized as JSON.
        return json.dumps(context)
```

This is how you would use it (also from the documentation):

```
class HybridDetailView(JSONResponseMixin,
                       SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin, BaseDetailView):
    def render_to_response(self, context):
        # Look for a 'format=json' GET argument
        if self.request.GET.get('format','html') == 'json':
            return JSONResponseMixin.render_to_response(self, context)
        else:
            return SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin.render_to_response(self, context)
```