# Django: Where do I place reusable functions?

Tags: python, django, django-views

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I include custom modules in a Django app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576060/how-can-i-include-custom-modules-in-a-django-app)

There are functions that I'd like to re-use in my views. Do I define them inside views.py? What is the "django way" to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen projects that use a `utils.py` file. If the functions inside only pertain to one app it goes in the apps directory.  If it is shared between apps it can go in an app called `common` or something to similar effect.